# .htaccess not working when url contains a path

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've searched stackoverflow and numerous websites for an answer to this. So please don't shoot me if it's already been answered on stackoverflow. I am stuck.

I just need a simple redirect where anything after my website name is put into a querystring of $target except for when a path is included in the url.

It doesn't work when a path is given.

eg)

- `mysite.com.au/home` to `mysite.com.au/?target=home`
- `mysite.com.au/home/` to `mysite.com.au/?target=home`
- `mysite.com.au/home/something` to `mysite.com.au/home/something`
- `mysite.com.au/home/something/` to `mysite.com.au/home/something`
- `mysite.com.au/home/something/file.php` to `mysite.com.au/home/something/file.php`

The below in my .htaccess file. It only works for condition 1 above.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ?target=$1
```

Can somebody show me a better/proper way for url redirects or know  how to do this?
I don't want to use specific 301 redirects.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: `/home/something/` is an existing path ?

Comment: ...And if `/home/something` exists, does it have its own .htaccess file?

Comment: I just have the one .htaccess file in the root directory. For the purposes of /home/something, if it exists I would want the contents of any index.php to show. If it didn't exist, I would want a 404 error returned.

Basically, anything like mysite.com/home I would want to redirect through a $target query string. Anything with a deeper path I want normal behaviour where nothing is redirected.

Comment: If you have _no other rewrite rules_, what you have posted above should work correctly (except for a trailing slash on `target=home/`. Is there anything else at all in this .htaccess?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put this code in your htaccess (which has to be in document root folder)

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /?target=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks Justin. This works except for when the url is mysite.com/something and the directory something exists. Then it displays my index.php from my root folder, but without any css. Any idea what is going on?

    

eg. craigieburncommunity.com.au/home redirects back to index.php with a GET[target] of home.

craigieburncommunity.com.au/home/blah gives a 404 error as expected because the directory doesn't exist.

craigieburncommunity.com.au/ui seems to be showing my index.php but is missing the css. This is a valid path.

Comment: `craigieburncommunity.com.au/home redirects back to index.php with a GET[target] of home` That's not what you wanted ? About your css problem, that's because you're using **relative** paths instead of **absolute** paths for all your html links (images, javascript, css, href links). To solve the problem, you can add this line after `<head>` html tag: `<base href="/">`

Comment: Sorry, yes I did want craigieburncommunity.com.au/home redirected to to index.php with a GET[target] of home. I should have made that clearer :)

The issue was when going to craigieburncommunity.com.au/ui and it was somehow displaying index.php from my root directory. However, if I create an index.php in craigieburncommunity.com.au/ui, that solves the problem. I'll make contents blank or similar to 404 error. Unless you know of a more elegant solution where I don't need to create an index.php in all my folders?

Comment: Whatever the case, think I have mostly what I need. I really appreciate your help. I'll mark your answer as the solution.